# Trouble with collision INSIDE an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay So I want to learn classes and I'm trying to learn some of the "wording" if you will, of how to set it up and organize. As in using code rather than the stage to setup objects! At the moment I'm creating several "tests" in this particular one though I can't seem to get FLASH to properly detect my hero! First I'll explain my layout. I have an object called theForest. Inside I have a layer for objects to interact with, objects to see and of course my collisions(walls). At the moment I have a lever stand and a lever piece that are separate and you need to collect the lever piece before touching the stand. I've done this many times with all objects on the stage. HOWEVER, in this particular instance I actually have my hero in the game through code. As in hero.x = 100 and same with the Y.

```
function itemPickUp(e:Event){
if(theForest.leverPiece.hitTestObject.hero){
    theForest.leverPiece.visible = false;
    missingLeverPiece = false;
}
}
```

Everything works PERFECTLY, but this line.... Keeps saying error, but it still runs, doesn't freeze. Idk if maybe I need to add this function to my loop function. As I mentioned this is simply for tests so I don't have a lot of code. If more is needed let me know and I shall add more of what I have! Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Also if this helps, in case I was't clear enough. I have theForest which contains as i mentioned my walls and my lever. The lever and walls are on different layers. My code is causing the background to scroll while the hero stays in the middle of the screen. Also, my hero isn't on the stage, he's strictly coded in which I think is causing the problem. This is my error I get---
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property hero not found on builtin.as$0.MethodClosure and there is no default value.
 at Somethingsomething_fla::MainTimeline/itemPickUp()

Comment: `if(theForest.leverPiece.hitTestObject(hero))` ?

Comment: As mentioned above, hitTestObject is a function.  Not an attribute/property.  Try what  @Vesper mentioned.

Comment: Thank you guys the did work.... *sigh* always seems to be something small that I overlook!!